# cakephp mysql ->having

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

как мне написать такой запрос в cakephp

SELECT * FROM `tickets` 
INNER JOIN `questions` ON (questions.id_ticket = tickets.id)
HAVING tickets.count_question = COUNT(tickets.id)

я пытаюсь так но оно не работает

```
$ticket = $this->Tickets->find()
->innerJoinWith('Questions')
->group('Tickets.id')
->having(['Tickets.count_question' => 'COUNT(Questions.id)']);
```

Comment: что-то у меня некоторые сомнения в адекватности исходного запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Укажите названия таблиц с маленькой буквы, т.к. в запросе у вас они с маленькой. Только в `innerJoinWith` должно быть с большой, т.к. туда передаётся название модели:

```
$ticket = $this->Tickets->find()
->innerJoinWith('Questions')
->group('tickets.id')
->having(['tickets.count_question' => 'COUNT(questions.id)']);
```

Если не поможет, попробуйте еще переписать `join` вот так:

```
$ticket = $this->Tickets->find()
->join([
    'questions' => [
        'table' => 'questions',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => 'questions.id_ticket = tickets.id',
    ]
])
->group('tickets.id')
->having(['tickets.count_question' => 'COUNT(questions.id)']);
```